# How can i build my own VAST capable video player?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js, video-player, vast

There are many vast capable libraries and players. But i want to build my own vast capable player for our own needs. From where should i start to learn or read something? Please suggest me any good reference and way.

Comment: What resources have you looked up already?

Answer (score 0):

I develop VAST/VPAID players.
Begin to read the IAB documentation:\n
VAST: http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VPAID_2_0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf\n
VPAID: http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VPAID_2_0_Final_04-10-2012.pdf

After that, I advice you to develop a small VAST Player with Javascript using the HTML5 video tag.

You can found sample VASTS here to test your app: http://www.iab.com/insights/vast-2-0-xml-samples-for-testing/

Good luck.